# Retrieving database values as tooltip on mouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website in asp.net with C# which displays some textboxes for stations data. I want code for displaying that stations details from SQL Server table as tooltip on mouseover event. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> use textbox MouseHover event

```
ToolTip ts = new ToolTip();
private void txtAlias_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           datatable dt= new datatable();
           dt=//bind datat in datatble from datatbese
           string sData=dt.row[0][0].ToString();//datat to displayed in tooltip
           ts.SetToolTip(this.txtAlias,sData.Trim() );
        }
```